# random choice based on percentage in python

Tags: python

I created this script

```
#!/c/Python/Python38-32/python

import sys
import random

copy = sys.argv[1]

p = random.choices( ["FeeSimple","Leasehold"], weights=(50, 50), k=int(copy))
print(p)
```

when i enter the copy as 6 - sometimes the result be

```
["FeeSimple","FeeSimple","FeeSimple","FeeSimple","Leasehold","Leasehold"] OR 
["FeeSimple","FeeSimple","FeeSimple","FeeSimple","FeeSimple","Leasehold"]
```

but what i want is to generate 3 of them as "FeeSimple" (50%) and the other as "Leasehold" (50%)

Note:
The copy variable can be any number from 1 to millions

Comment: Create a larger array, and it'll reach 50/50 odds. Like flipping a coin. You can also remove the weights argument if you want equal probability

Comment: So you don't want random choices, but a random order (`random.shuffle`) of a fixed number of elements?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the behavior of `choices`, each time it makes a choice it has a 50/50 chance of choosing one or the other. It won't necessarily result in an array that is 50/50. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to always get a 1:1 ratio of elements, but a random *distribution*. If so, [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) is the wrong tool for the job since its ratio is random, though weighted. Instead, make a k-sized list of the elements, then shuffle it with [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
import random

copy = 6
k = copy // 2
x = ["FeeSimple", "Leasehold"] * k
random.shuffle(x)
print(x)
```

Example output:

```
['FeeSimple', 'Leasehold', 'Leasehold', 'FeeSimple', 'FeeSimple', 'Leasehold']
```

Comment: it is not always 50 50 sometimes i will want it as 80 20

Comment: @lala Oh, that's not really clear from the question. So you want 50/50 min, and 80/20 max? Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64731362/edit) to clarify.

Comment: @lala I'm thinking you could make a list of 50 of A and 20 of B, then fill in the remaining 30 with `choices`, then shuffle the result.